# How to list all files (or only certains type of files) inside a main folder and all its subfolders in Google Drive using GAS?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

Is it possible to create a Google Apps Script which would list :

**1) all filenames inside a specific main folder (and in each of its related subfolders)** ?

Example :

Root\Photos\02.jpg

Root\Photos\03.jpg

...

Root\Photos\2010\02.jpg

Root\Photos\2010\2010-02\03.jpg

...

**2)** same than with 1) but **only filenames finishing by ".ini"** (as for instance I have some unwanted ".picasa.ini" files that are inside my online google drive) ?

Answer (score 1):

Since it appears you have (really) a lot of files and folders in your drive, I guess the first thing to do would be to know all the folders and subfolders you have in your drive, the script below will create a second sheet in your spreadsheet and show all the folders and their respective trees + urls.

It shows also the total execution time in seconds, I don't have to remind you that this value should not exceed +-300 seconds...

So I suggest you try it and report the resulting time here before we can go further.

```
function listFolders(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  if(!ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2')){ss.insertSheet(1).setName('Sheet2')};
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var start = new Date();
  var dateString = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getTimeZone(), 'MMM-dd-yyyy');
  var topFolder = DocsList.getRootFolder() ; // start point
  var foldersArray = [];
  foldersArray = getFolders(topFolder.getName().replace('Root','MyDrive'),topFolder,foldersArray);
  foldersArray.unshift(['Folders url','path','# SubFolders']);
  //    Logger.log(foldersArray)
  var l = foldersArray.length
  var duration = (new Date().getTime()-start.getTime())/1000;
  var durationString = Utilities.formatString("%01.1f", duration)
  sh.clear();
  sh.setColumnWidth(2,500);
  sh.getRange(1,1,1,foldersArray[0].length).setBackground('#ffffaa').setBorder(true,true,true,true,true,true).setFontWeight('bold');
  sh.getRange(1,1,l,foldersArray[0].length).setValues(foldersArray).setVerticalAlignment('middle').setWrap(false);  
  sh.getRange(l+1,2,1,foldersArray[0].length-1)
  sh.getRange(l+1,1).setFontColor('grey').setFontSize(9).setVerticalAlignment('middle').setWrap(true).setHorizontalAlignment('center').setValue('execution time: '+durationString+' Seconds');
  sh.setFrozenRows(1);
}

function getFolders(path, container,arrayin) {
  var folders = container.getFolders(0, 500);
  var folderCount = folders.length;
  if(path=='MyDrive'){arrayin.push(['https://drive.google.com/?hl=fr&tab=wo#my-drive',path,folderCount])}
  else{arrayin.push([container.getUrl(),path,folderCount])}

  for (var i=0;i<folders.length;i++) {
    var thisFolder = folders[i].getName();
    var thisPath = path+"/"+thisFolder;
    getFolders(thisPath,folders[i],arrayin)
  }
  return arrayin;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. ;) I 've created a new google spreadsheet. Added your script. Run it. One one minute later I got the red error : "Could not connect to server". I waited a few minutes then run again the function "listFolders". Then I got the same error. I waited a few minutes, then I got this error : http://hpics.li/ca36018  Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: well, try what they suggest... but I'm afraid you will again exceed max time :-/ worth trying anyway !

Comment: Thanks Serge. I have tried and get "Exceeded maximum execution time" http://hpics.li/d5026cf Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: You will have to implement a timer triggered partial batch processing as I did in the other script... a bit of coding exercise to play with :-) , good luck.

Comment: Thanks.;) By using your previous help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22736141/how-to-find-duplicates-files-by-name-and-or-size-in-a-specific-folder-of-my-go and trying some examples from there https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/docs-list/docs-list, I was able to make it list all subfolders of one folder. ;) Alas when I try either to add :  a) a timer with a partial batch processing, I am stuck to what I have to add with folder-iterator https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder-iterator or...

Comment: ...b) a listing of all files inside the main folder and its subfolders. Here is my testing code : http://cjoint.com/?DDfk0gp8ttu  Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: I also have tried to find a way to get filenames finishing by ".ini". see my test code here : http://cjoint.com/?DDfmNFTrCsB thanks ;)

Comment: Hello, By luck could anyone provide some more help? I am lost! Many thanks in advance ;)