# Copy row from table if value in table meets condition

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I saw this post about [Google Apps Script - Copy row from table if value in table meets condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25038715/google-apps-script-copy-row-from-table-if-value-in-table-meets-condition). Is there any way to do the same with gsheet formula and not apps script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with `QUERY` or `FILTER` approach.

#### Query:

- `=query({A2:C5}, "select * where Col1='A'")`

#### Filter:

- `=filter(A2:C5, A2:A5 = "A")`

#### Outputs:

[image: output]

#### Note:

- I recommend using filter if data is simpler and can be written as a single range.
- I recommend using query for complicated/composite data via combining columns coming from different sheets, or columns not beside each other and needs to be put into array (e.g. `{A1:A, C1:C}, etc.`)